# How to add new angular components at runtime?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm developing an application where I have Plugins that can be installed at runtime.

Within the plugins we have both Spring features and angular components.

Is there any way to include these new angular components in a runtime application?

I'm using the default stack generated by angular-cli.